# How to write query in sp.?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Table A :

```
Unique_code   Deal_No   Option   Aount
1234          155-12     Sell     100
1234          155-12     Buy      200
5678          155-13     Sell     300
9101          155-14     Buy      400
```

Need :

```
Unique_code   Deal_No    Option     Aount
1234          155-12      Sell     300
5678          155-13      Sell     300
9101          155-14      Buy      400
```

i need to the sum of uniq code.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you please paste in your code, even if it is not complete.

Comment: i try Table A Data dump in Table B as temp table. And Inner Join to the two table base on unique_code. but row is increased.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple group by and sum will give results:

```
Select Unique_code, Deal_no, Sum(Amount) as Amount
   from yourtable
group by Unique_code, Deal_no
```

You can query as below if you have multiple columns:

```
Select * from (
   Select *, Sum_Amount = Sum(Amount) over(partition by Unique_Code,  Deal_No),
      RowN = Row_Number() over(partition by Unique_code, Deal_No order by [option] desc)
      from yourtable ) a
   Where a.RowN = 1
```

Comment: Actually Table A have multiple column then not possible to Group By clause.

Comment: This Is Error:
Column 'A.name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: you added all the columns apart from sum in select in group by?

Comment: it is not possible to added all columns in group by. bcz 43 columns present in my Select Query. How can i possible ??

Comment: In that case use this query in sub query with required unique columns and join with that columns

Comment: For first two rows why you need to get 'Sell' not 'Buy'?